# Not able to successfully run websphere traditional container in minikube ( kubernetes )

Tags: kubernetes, websphere-8

Following the documentation from https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/ I was able to successfully deploy the WebSphere traditional image to Docker and access the admin console as described in the document.

Then I tried to deploy the same image to minikube ( kubernetes ). It seems to deploy successfully. But I'm not able to access the admin console.

Here are the commands I ran,

```
kubectl run websphere-traditional  --image="ibmcom/websphere-traditional:install"   --port=9443 --port=9043

kubectl expose deployment websphere-traditional --type=NodePort --name=websphere-traditional --port=9043 

minikube service websphere-traditional --url
Returned http://192.168.99.100:30030
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but WAS full profile console is usually exposed on ports 9060 and 9043:

`http://yourserver:9060/ibm/console`
or
`https://yourserver:9043/ibm/console`

WAS full profile also exposes much more ports (SOAP, IIOP, JMS etc..)